# Comparison operators vs “rich comparison” methods in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, comparison-operators

Can someone explain me the differences between the two. Are those normally equivalent ? Maybe I'm completely wrong here, but I thought that each comparison operator was necessarily related to one *“rich comparison”* method. This is from the documentation:

> The correspondence between operator symbols and method names is as
>   follows:
>
> `x<y` calls `x.__lt__(y)`, `x<=y` calls `x.__le__(y)`, `x==y` calls `x.__eq__(y)`, `x!=y` calls `x.__ne__(y)`, `x>y` calls `x.__gt__(y)`, and `x>=y` calls `x.__ge__(y)`.

Here is an example that demonstrates my confusion.

**Python 3.x:**

```
dict1 = {1:1}
dict2 = {2:2}

>>> dict1 < dict2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'
>>> dict1.__lt__(dict2)
NotImplemented
```

**Python 2.x:**

```
dict1 = {1:1}
dict2 = {2:2}

>>> dict1 < dict2
True
>>> dict1.__lt__(dict2)
NotImplemented
```

From the python 3 example, it seems logic that calling `dict1 < dict2` is not supported. But what about Python 2 example ? Why is it accepted ?

I know that unlike Python 2, in Python 3, not all objects supports comparison operators. At my surprise though, both version return the `NotImplemented` singleton when calling `__lt__()`.

Comment: On second thought, I misread. Will reopen.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Hmmm, the question is significantly differrent from mine. It does not explain the difference between the two and does not provide any insight on when `NotImplemented` is returned...

Comment: I also find funny the fact that `<` and `__lt__` do not return the same result. They should be since `<` calls `__lt__`, right?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Yes, this is my confusion. I always taken for granted that both were almost essentially the same. Can you confirm that it indeed does not return the same thing ? Maybe it is a code problem ?

Comment: @scharette I can. Tried it with Python 3.6.1. We need to wait for the big guns on this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is relying on the `__cmp__` magic method, which is what the rich-comparison operators were meant to replace:

```
>>> dict1 = {1:1}
>>> dict2 = {2:2}
>>> dict1.__cmp__
<method-wrapper '__cmp__' of dict object at 0x10f075398>
>>> dict1.__cmp__(dict2)
-1
```

As to the ordering *logic*, here is the Python 2.7 [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons):

> Mappings (instances of dict) compare equal if and only if they have
>   equal (key, value) pairs. Equality comparison of the keys and values
>   enforces reflexivity.
>
> Outcomes other than equality are resolved consistently, but are not
>   otherwise defined.

With a footnote:

> Earlier versions of Python used lexicographic comparison of the sorted
>   (key, value) lists, but this was very expensive for the common case of
>   comparing for equality. An even earlier version of Python compared
>   dictionaries by identity only, but this caused surprises because
>   people expected to be able to test a dictionary for emptiness by
>   comparing it to {}.

And, in Python 3.0, ordering has been simplified. This is from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons):

> The ordering comparison operators `(<, <=, >=, >)` raise a TypeError
>   exception when the operands don’t have a meaningful natural ordering.
>
> `builtin.sorted()` and `list.sort()` no longer accept the cmp argument
>   providing a comparison function. Use the key argument instead.
>
> The `cmp()` function should be treated as gone, and the `__cmp__()` special method
>   is no longer supported. Use `__lt__()` for sorting, `__eq__()` with
>   `__hash__()`, and other rich comparisons as needed. (If you really need the `cmp()` functionality, you could use the expression `(a > b) - (a <> b)` as the equivalent for `cmp(a, b)`.)

So, to be explicit, in Python 2, since the rich comparison operators are not implemented, `dict` objects will fall-back to `__cmp__`, from the data-model [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__):

> `object.__cmp__(self, other)`
>   Called by comparison operations if rich
>   comparison (see above) is not     defined. Should return a negative
>   integer if self < other, zero if self     == other, a positive integer
>   if self > other.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it does not seems to answer my above questions. Maybe it is because I don't understand and if it is, I'm sorry. I still don't understand why both implementation is not returning the same value. It is clearly mention that when comparing two objects with the `<`, `__lt__()` is called. This is obviously not the case in my example.

Comment: @scharette yes, as explained, in Python 2, `__cmp__` is a fall-back if rich comparison operators are not defined. Your misunderstanding is that `<` is always associated with `__lt__()` which is *not the case* in Python 2 because it was still supporting the legacy `__cmp__` method, which `dict` objects *did use*

Comment: Ok, so for dict, `__lt__` is not defined even in python 2?

Comment: Yes, I was just confused why does Python 2 and Python 3 did not result in the same output. but from what I understand now, `__cmp__` is not use in Python 3 anymore.

Comment: Just a suggestion, I would specify that the ordering has been change in python 3 according to this [link](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons)
 Thank you so much for leading me there.

Comment: @scharette: A `dict.__lt__` method exists, for reasons stemming from the C implementation (all rich comparisons map to one C function pointer in CPython, so if a C type has any rich comparison methods, it has to have all of them), but it always returns `NotImplemented`.

Comment: @scharette Python 2 and Python 3 are different languages. Python 2 kept a lot of baggage around from even early versions of Python. Consider the fact that the `<>` operator is still supported in Python 2! Note, rich-comparisons were only added in Python 2.1 I believe, before, *everything* used `__cmp__`. This is similar to why in Python 2 you can still pass a `cmp=` argument to `sorted` instead of `key=`, and Python 3 doesn't support `cmp`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Why does `OrderedDict` not supporting comparison operators then ? Is it just not implemented or there is another reason? If this is another topic I can ask another question on Stack maybe ?

Comment: @scharette sounds like another topic. But `OrderedDict` is a mapping, which, as pointed out by the docs, "Outcomes other than equality are resolved consistently, but are not otherwise defined."

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, but this is considering there is no ordering, which is the case for a `dict` object, but not for an `OrderedDict`. I think will ask another question on that subject. Thanks !

Comment: @scharette that says nothing about ordered mappings vs unordered mappings, it simply says *mappings*. But then even if you are using an ordered dict, why assume insertion order is how you want to compare things? You can always implement your own way to compare them explicitly.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I was reffering to python 3 documentation, where it says _The ordering comparison operators (<, <=, >=, >) raise a TypeError exception when the operands don’t have a meaningful natural ordering._

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Because, calling `list(1,2,3) == list(3,2,1)` will return `False`, whitout implementing my own way to compare them explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Note for operator `<` versus `__lt__`:

```
import types

class A:
    def __lt__(self, other): return True

def new_lt(self, other): return False

a = A()
print(a < a, a.__lt__(a))  # True True
a.__lt__ = types.MethodType(new_lt, a)
print(a < a, a.__lt__(a))  # True False
A.__lt__ = types.MethodType(new_lt, A)
print(a < a, a.__lt__(a))  # False False
```

`<` calls `__lt__` defined on class; `__lt__` calls `__lt__` defined on object.

It's usually the same :) And it is totally delicious to use: `A.__lt__ = new_lt`

Comment: A very interesting note! Thank you!